# <variable is not NSBundle> displayed for NSBundle:bundleForClass object

Tags: ios

If I execute this line

```
 NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[MyClass class]];
```

Then in the watch window it says:

```
bundle = (NSBundle*) 0x1fdc9d0 <variable is not NSBundle>.
```

Although the code executes without a problem and I can make use of the bundle within issue.

Why is it saying this?

Comment: Are you seeing this when you're exactly at that line of code or after passing it to the next line?

Comment: On the next line, after its executed.

Comment: If you right-click on the variable in watch window and choose "Print Description of bundle" what do you see?

Comment: NSBundle </var/mobile/Applications/337B7CC9-5EB9-4037-ABDE-6AD3F317CE72/My App.app>

Comment: Then everything is ok. It's just another *small* issue in Xcode :)

Comment: Thanks, one of many many small issues.

Comment: @Mungbeans: If you have access to pre-release software, you could check if this has been fixed in Xcode 5, and file a bug if it hasn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a display issue with Xcode. The variable does really have a valid value and pointing to the right object in memory, but the watch window can't recognize it for some reason.